# Plotly disable "band behavior" zoom selection

Tags: javascript, plotly

Is it possible to disable the "band behavior" plotly displays when doing a selection zoom?

To illustrate, these first two pictures are examples of moving into "band mode" when I am selecting and move the mouse too negative in the y or x axis.
[image]
[image]
What I want is to enforce behavior where selection only allows you do this kind of selecting:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
layout.xaxis.fixedrange: true
layout.yaxis.fixedrange: true
```

https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#layout-xaxis-fixedrange